# Unable to go to bios settings and stuck at gdm.service

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, bios, gdm

Logged off from my Ubuntu 20.04 and restarted the system. When I'm trying to check bios settings, my system is getting stuck at gdm.service [Stuck at gdm.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZT4.jpg)

I tried to plug my usb drive and usb cable also, but it is giving me 'unable to enumerate USB device' error.
[USB device issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFCcj.jpg)

Also normal starts are not working. Stuck at Ubuntu icon.

Comment: Accessing BIOS or UEFI (the former is more likely if your computer is from 2012 or newer) is independent of the OS (it may not have one installed at all). When the OS starts to load is already too late. You need to power on and immediately press, spam or long press the specific key to access UEFI settings.

Comment: It worked thanks...